# Yii2 send event from php to clients using yii2-nod-socket

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, yii

I am using [yii2-node-socket](https://github.com/oncesk/yii-node-socket) to send event to clients in a concrete room. I followed all steps to install the extension in my project, the server was started successfully and the client was connected to socket but when I tried to send event from php code the client did not receive any data.

Javascript code:

```
var socket = new YiiNodeSocket();
socket.onConnect(function () {
socket.room('testRoom').join(function (success, numberOfRoomSubscribers) {
    // success - boolean, numberOfRoomSubscribers - number of room members
    // if error occurred then success = false, and numberOfRoomSubscribers - contains error message
    if (success) {
        console.log(numberOfRoomSubscribers + ' clients in room: testRoom');
        // do something

        // bind events
        this.on('join', function (newMembersCount) {
            // fire on client join
        });

        this.on('data', function (data) {
            // fire when server send frame into this room with 'data' event
            console.log('in data : ', data);
        });
    } else {
        // numberOfRoomSubscribers - error message
        alert(numberOfRoomSubscribers);
    }
});
});
```

PHP code:

```
    // create frame
    $frame = Yii::$app->nodeSocket->getFrameFactory()->createEventFrame();

    // set event name
    $frame->setEventName('data');

    // set room name
    $frame->setRoom('testRoom');

    // set data
    $frame['key'] = 'hello';

    // send
    $frame->send();
```

Comment: You got any Solution?